# Add Ads to RecyclerView every x items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of items that I want to insert into `RecyclerView`.

Inside the `RecyclerView` I had like that every 5th item an Ad will be inserted.

The thing is that if for example I have 10 Items, I had like it to be:

```
-item 1-
-item 2-
-item 3-
-item 4-
- Ads -
-item 5-
-item 6-
-item 7-
-item 8-
- Ads -
-item 9-
-item 10-
```

While what im getting is:

```
-item 1-
-item 2-
-item 3-
-item 4-
- Ads -
-item 6-
-item 7-
-item 8-
-item 9-
- Ads -
```

and it deletes the 5th and 10th items and places Ad instead.

How can I make the RecyclerView to Insert an item instead of replacing it?

My RecyclerView is as follows:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position!=0 && position%5 == 0) {
        return AppConstants.IS_ADS_POSITION;
    }
    return AppConstants.IS_NOT_ADS_POSITION;
}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View view;
    switch (viewType) {
        default:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_item_myitem, viewGroup, false);
            return new DiscoveritemsViewHolder(view);
        case AppConstants.IS_ADS_POSITION:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.native_ad, viewGroup, false);
            return new NativeAdViewHolder(view);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (!(holder instanceof DiscoveritemsViewHolder)){
        showAdView((MyitemsAdapter.NativeAdViewHolder) holder, position);
    } else {
        ((MyitemsAdapter.DiscoveritemsViewHolder) holder).bind( (discoveritems.get( position )) );
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return discoveritems.size();
}




public class NativeAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public NativeAdViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        MobileAds.initialize(itemView.getContext(), AppConstants.APP_ADS_ID);
        AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(itemView.getContext(), itemView.getContext().getResources().getString( R.string.Native_Ads ))
                .forUnifiedNativeAd(new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                        NativeTemplateStyle styles = new
                                NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().withMainBackgroundColor(new ColorDrawable(itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor( R.color.colorLockedPurple ))).build();

                        TemplateView template = (TemplateView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_template);
                        template.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 300));
                        template.setStyles(styles);
                        template.setNativeAd(unifiedNativeAd);

                    }
                })
                .build();

        adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

}

private void showAdView(MyitemsAdapter.NativeAdViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

}
```

The code where I populate the list prior to inserting it to the RecyclerView:

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
    MyItems.add( new DiscoverItems(document.getString( "ItemID" ) ));
}
myItemsAdapter = new MyItemsAdapter(MyItems, listener);

rv_MyItems.setAdapter(myItemsAdapter);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is change your `getItemCount()` return, Because if you want to add items to your list you need to update the size of your list with it.

For your use you want your list to iterate of 1 every 5 items so your `getItemCount()` should be something like this `return list.size + (list.size / 5)`

Comment: Any chance to give fuller example? I couldnt understand mate

Comment: Do you still need help with it ? I've forgot to answer your comment

Answer (score 0):

Your data should manage recyclerview, but not vice versa.

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)  
val listWithAds = mutableListOf<Int>()  
list.chunked(4).forEach {
        listWithAds.addAll(it)
        listWithAds.add(AdsItem())
}

result: [1, 2, 3, 4, AdsItem(), 5, 6, 7, 8, AdsItem(), 9, 10, AdsItem()] ...
```